# yahoo boss - inlinks - confused!

Tags: php, zend-framework, seo, yahoo

I am confused with `Yahoo Site Explorer API` and `BOSS site explorer`.

Is it the same thing?

I am currently using Zend 's implementations of the ySE api.
If I understand well, the api is going to be stopped this month.
Is the BOSS version going to remain and if so it will be paid/free?

Is there some stable PHP library that will handle BOSS site explorer api?

Answer (score 1):

to my knowledge BOSS will be migrated (at some point in the future) to BING as everything else from yahoo search. if BING will offer BOSS as it is or introduce BOSS 2.0 is still unclear (but my guess is, it will be a BOSS 2.0 as BING and YAHOO search are two very different beasts)

developing anything currently on a yahoo plattform for the long term (especially in the search field) is not recommended.

i don't know of any boss php api, but a google search search quite a lot, don't know whats best.

Comment: oh, and no Yahoo Site Explorer API and BOSS site explorer are two different tools (with two different logics) but based on the same index.